# Simply javascript jQuery code working in Chrome, not Firefox, Safari, IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple bit of jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // fade in content.
    $('.coming_soon').fadeIn(5000);
    });
</script>
```

Website:  [Classic Car Gallery Test](http://test3.chuprinastudios.com)

It works quite nicely in Chrome with the "coming soon" image fading in nicely.  Unfortunately this does not work in Firefox, Safari, and IE.  What have I done wrong?  Any input, advice or code snippets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think your image is shown before you call fadeIn.
putting some css to hide your image (display:none on .coming_soon) should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.coming_soon').hide().fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: Because jquery is called on document ready, won't the image show onload and only be hidden once dom is ready?

Comment: @Marc - technically, no. jQuery's document ready runs as soon as the HTML has loaded into the DOM, as compared to the javascript `.onload()`, which runs once *all external files* have finished loading into the browser, which is the definition of a ready DOM.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I have always wondered about this and have set my styles instead of using .hide().

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is a crossbrowser framework, so should work fine. Make sure your `.coming_soon` tag is set to `display:none;` in your css.

e.g.

```
.coming_soon {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide it first :)

`display:none` would be better solution than `.hide()` as it happens before JS is loaded

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/z3tpS/1/

Comment: BUT - if you set `display:none` using CSS and someone views the page who has javascript disabled, then they'll never see the image.  It's better to set it with javascript.